# Passing functions to jQuery with missing parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I've noticed that sometimes when I'm passing a callback function in jQuery, I can get away with not having the function specify all the parameters.

For example, in the `.each()` function, it takes a function which has parameters `index,Element`. However you can use give it fewer parameters than that as evident in the first example in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/): `$('li').each(function(index){...}`.

When is this valid? And why is this syntactically valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What jQuery does is examine the type of the parameters you passed and figures out what you meant.  That gives you some flexibility in what you include.  This only works when the expected parameters are a different type.  For example, if you have three possible parameters for a function: a string, a number and a function, then the receiving function can examine the type of each parameter and figure out which is which no matter what order they are passed in or which ones are included.

In jQuery, there is usually only one parameter that's a function so, jQuery can pretty much find it no matter where it is in the parameter list.

If, on the other hand, the function took two strings or two functions as parameters, then those would have to be passed in the right order so the receiving function could know which was which.

This can work in javascript because:

1. If a parameter is not passed to a function, javascript just sets the resulting argument to the function to "undefined" allowing the calling function to see that it was missing when called.
2. Javascript allows one to examine the types of variables so in this case, the calling function can look at the different types of what was passed and modify it's behavior.

If you look at the click() function, you see jQuery has three possible ways to use it:

```
.click()
.click( handler(eventObject) )
.click( [eventData,] handler(eventObject) )
```

Internally, the click function in jQuery is declared like this:

```
function (data, handler)
```

Then, when that function is called jQuery looks at the parameters data and handler and determines that if both parameters are undefined, then the caller must have done:

```
.click();
```

If only the handler parameter is undefined and the data parameter is defined and is a function type, then the caller must have used the second form of:

```
.click(handler)
```

In this case, jQuery internally does this to put the parameters into the right slots before using them:

```
handler = data;
data = null;
```

If both parameters are not undefined, then the caller must have used:

```
.click(data, handler)
```

and it can use both parameters as declared.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. Accepted for explaining how jQuery handles out-of-order arguments.

Comment: Your welcome.  jQuery secrets are revealed if you just step through a few function calls in a debugger in Chrome or Firebug and see how it works.

Answer (score 6):

In Javascript you do not have to pass all the parameters to a function. If you don't pass one, it has a default value of undefined.

Comment: This works for trailing parameters omitted. There is no implicit way to omit leading parameters. Because of this is is often helpful to consider the most *useful* parameters and put them first in the callbacks so that `function (important) {}` can be used in place of `function (imporant, extra) {}` or vice-versa, as in the post. One thing to note is `arguments.length` will change based on how many parameters were supplied in the function invocation.

Answer (score 1):

It's always valid. A function declaration in JavaScript provides names for parameters, but doesn't otherwise constrain how the function can be invoked. In other words, functions have no "type signature" as they do in some other languages.

A function can always be called with as many parameters as you like, regardless of how it was defined.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of JavaScript and not jQuery. You can pass any number of parameters when you call it. Now it depends in the function what you are looking for. Also you can retrieve the function parameter using arguments keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It is always valid.  In javascript you can call any function with more or less parameters than defined.  So, your function naming no parameters will still get passed those two parameters.  You can even see the value of the parameters by using `arguments`.  `arguments[0]` will be `index`, etc.